# Getting error : The contents of this item cannot be retrieved. When installing the p12 file in Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, certificate, keychain

I am trying to enable push notification in my app for which I followed the following link to generate an app provisioning profile and certificate.p12 file.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

The public and private key pair are visible in my keychain. However, when I am double clicking on the xx.p12 file downloaded in my system, I am asked for the password, where I tried both my system password as well as private key password but still I am getting this issue: An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.

What am I missing here? I have xx.certSigningRequest as well in my system.  I am not sure if I have to double click to install the xx.p12 file and run my app to enable push. What should be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete any already imported certificate from system.
2. Remove private and public keys from Keychain.
3. Revoke old certificate in case above two doesn't work.

This worked for me! Hope the same for others.

Answer (score 0):

I got this too. All i know is it's not the system password but the one which you created when it asked for it. Plus I don't remember the tutorial asking that file to be clicked anyway. I'm following it as typing this.